# Changing HTML elements through JS doesn't update immediately

Tags: javascript, html

On my website I have quite large 3d model files that need to be loaded and I want to show the user how many 3d objects are already loaded. I created two variables, that get incremented when an object is requested or loaded successfully. Printing this out on console works, but I want to change two HTML outputs I created like this:

```
Loaded objects: <output id="loaded"></output>
Requested objects: <output id="requested"></output>
```

to show the current status. To update the numbers I use these commands:

```
function updateLoadNumbers() {
    document.getElementById("loaded").value = loadedObjects;
    document.getElementById("requested").value = requestedObjects;
}
```

I call this function, when a new object has been created and I call it when an object has been successfully processed. The latter happens at the end of an callback that was started by an `XMLHttpRequest`.

This is a shortened version of the code:

```
function loadFileAsText(filename, callback) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //setting up the request

  req.onload = function() {
    if(req.status >= 200 && req.status < 300 || req.status == 0)
      callback(req.responseText);
  };
}


//Part of the function to process a file
loadFileAsText(filename, (result) => {
    /*
    All the processing
    */

    loadedObjects++;
    updateLoadNumbers();
}
```

**But the text only updated when the loading is done**, when it is useless. How can I get the HTML to update faster?

Comment: Well, how do you fire those commands? In an onload event?

Comment: how do you load your objects ? using xhr ?

Comment: @ceejayoz when creating an object and when finishing the load in an unload function

Comment: @A.RAZIK yes, I use XMLHttpRequests

Comment: You need to show a full example.

Comment: @GuyIncognito what part of the code do you need?

Comment: In your completed callback function, couldn't you grab the length at the very beginning and increment and show it at that point?

Comment: All relevant code. See [mcve]. If you set the value of an element it will update immediately unless something is blocking it, we need to see probably the entire function to tell what that something is. Or if there's some other fault in the logic.

Comment: @user11914177 and another thing what does this file contain? is it just a JSON file of objects?

Comment: @A.RAZIK I guess I used the term object a bit loosely, with object I mean an 3D object model file, which is just a text file

Comment: @user11914177 so then you can visualize just the progress of your xhr request, if you want just do that you need to setup a callback for you xhr object

Comment: @A.RAZIK I don't think you understood my problem, the problem is not, that my variables are not incrementing right, the problem is, that the variables don't update on the html site

Comment: @user11914177 the two variables that you are using are just numbers, right ?

Comment: @A.RAZIK yes, they say how many objects have been requested / loaded

Comment: *"I call this function, when a new object has been created and I call it when an object has been successfully processed, which happens in the callback function of an XMLHttpRequest."* <-- it's missing the code for that function, the function that creates the object, the function that makes the Ajax request, and the callback function. But sure, I'll leave the question alone and hope that someone comes along and makes a really good guess.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Well I can assume that the problem is somewhere else, because from my knowledge of JS this code shouldn't be wrong, I try if I can improve the question

Comment: @GuyIncognito I added more code

Answer (score 0):

If I got what do you want to achieve then:

first, you need correct HTML tags like this:

```
Loaded objects: <span id="loaded"></span>
Requested objects: <span id="requested"></span>
```

and just fill the `textContent` of each of them inside the `onprogress` callback which has an event that includes two information that you need here, `event.loaded` the bytes the browser received and `event.total` the total bytes set by the header. so your code might look like that:

```
var loadedInfo = document.getElementById("loaded");
var requestedInfo = document.getElementById("requested");

xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(event){
   loadedInfo.textContent = event.loaded;
   requestedInfo.textContent = event.total;
});
```

If you are not familiar with xhr requests yet I recommend you to check this : [XmlHTTPRequest MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Thats not fixing my problem, the problem is, that the values only show up, after the objects are loaded, but if they are they show up correct

Comment: now should be clear how you can do it after your question edition

Comment: I don't have a single request, I have many and I just want to count how many have already finished. I also edited my question to clear it up further

Comment: so just put how you are doing your many requests because we can't just wast time with guessing.

Comment: This question really isn't about how I do many requests, but about how the site doesn't update and I hope the code in my question shows you how I do the updates